# Unable to locate adb issue with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

As the title said, I manage to install Android Studio with the Flutter plugin in my "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS" PC... I also installed the Android SDK (API 28) Everything works fine until i start to start the emulator, i got this message

[image: Error alert]

The problem is that the emulator works fine after its launch and any modifications in my code will be applied on the emulator!!!

This is another screen-shot of my Android SDK-Tools components:

[image: Sdk-Tools]

**By the way, the adb file exist in the android-platforms folder.**

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: what you see if you run `adb` from the terminal window? also: does `flutter doctor -v` show anything "in red"?

Comment: Hi, you can find the output on the following link  [https://pastebin.com/egkabbZ3 ]

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same issue.

My environment: Mac OS Catalina ver.10.15.6.

I tried this way which was suggested on the other platform and I solved this issue.

[Project Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqvJJ.png)

you go to File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project, and select the Project SDK, which is set to [No SDK] by default.

If there's nothing in the drop-down box, then select New, select Android SDK, and navigate to your Android SDK location. You will then be able to select the Android API xx Platform. Now that you should not get this annoying adb error.

I am not sure if this would work for you. But give it a try!